# Real Analysis - Absolute Values

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody explain me this step? How did we get rid of absolute values?

$||\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|-r| < \epsilon$

implies

$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|-r < \epsilon$

Comment: Removing the absolute values can only make the LHS smaller, so it is still less than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $|x|<A$ means that $-A < x < A$. Thus, if $|x|<A$, then $x<A$ by definition

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|<\varepsilon$, this implies that $a<\varepsilon$. Because if $a\geq0$, then $|a|=a$ and the inequality is trivial. If $a<0$, then $a<\varepsilon$ too.